# Python and preventing email header injections

Tags: python, email, header, code-injection

I am currently creating a web contact form in python. My main aim is to teach myself python and I am not using a framework (just raw python). I am using python 2.5 as that is what my webhost has.

Sending email seems simple in python and that is clear in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html). The problem I have is that I can not find any clear examples on how to prevent header injection attacks when using a module such as smtplib.

It seems like one thing that is important to get right but going by [python bugs](http://bugs.python.org/issue5871) that I can reproduce, it seems rather hard. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your script sends two newlines (CRLF to be compliant with relevant RFCs, LF only to be compliant with most MTAs) after the headers *you* want, and any attempted injected headers will show up in the email body.

Also, of course, do sanity-checks on the from:, to: and any other data input by a user to make sure no embedded headers or newlines are in those fields.